# Is something making my Eclipse IDE autocomplete really...unhelpful?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I'm using Eclipse:

```
 Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Juno Service Release 2
Build id: 20130225-0426
```

Happy user for years, but something has lately started bugging me and I'm not sure if I'm losing my mind on this, or something has changed.

Autocomplete is suggesting rather unhelpful classes in situations when it should (and I thought usually did) know better, for example:

[image: not helpful]

So my question is just, is this normal?

Comment: Could this help? no idea... http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/